# use variable with window.location.href

Tags: javascript, variables, window, location, href

I was wondering how I would be able to execute a command such as this in javascript. I just want to store the url as a string in a variable and redirect them to it when the time comes -

```
var linkz = "http://www.google.com/";
window.location.href= linkz;
```

Why doesn't this work?

Thanks,

Comment: That should work.  Your problem is elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using links this way (as mentioned in a comment):

```
<a href="javascript:checkCk(google.com)">Google</a>
```

Then the problem is that you're not passing a string to your `checkCk()` function.

**Try this**:

```
<a href="javascript:checkCk('http://google.com')">Google</a>
```

The code you used for `window.location.href` should work.

At this point, I don't see why you'd use javascript if all you're doing is replacing the default behavior of the link.

Comment: That fixed it. I can't believe I didn't see that =.= Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried on my local machine, and it works:

```
<script>

window.onload = function(){
    var google = "http://google.com";
    window.location.href = google;
}
</script>
Redirecting to google...
```

Copy this to new file, call it for example `redirect.html` and open it in your browser.

**Update:**

```
<script>

var redirect = function(new_place) {
    window.location.href = new_place;
}

</script>
<a href='javascript:redirect("http://google.com")'>Go to google</a>
```

Comment: the only place I could see, is when I pass it - <a href="javascript:checkCk(http://www.google.com)">Google</a>   but whats wrong? :(

Comment: What do you mean? What is checkCk?

Comment: its the function and the function is just function checkCK(linkz) { window.location.href=linkz;}

Comment: @ Matt. Copy code from my answer, and make a new file test.html. Try it. Will it work? (It will). Than it means - something wrong with your code (earlier - what we can't see)

Comment: @ Matt. Look at my answer again - I'll add there in `update` session new code. It works too.